Previous objects in the list of objects are getting modified on adding the last object to the list
Why the previous objects get updated when last element is added in the list?
I am creating the objects inside the loop, setting their properties, adding them to their list.
But upon adding the last object, all of the previous objects get modified.
In each iteration the memberlist tDat, is getting set as empty, but on the last iteration, it gets set as non-empty, and all the previous objects in the catList that were having ttDat as empty, now have the same non empty data.
I am not sure, what wrong am i doing here. And what can i do to resolve this.
List<String> tDat = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> ans = new ArrayList<>();

String a = " ";
String b = " ";
String c= " ";
String d= " ";
String e= " ";

List<Category> catList = new ArrayList<>();
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();

for(MainEvent event : mainEventList)
{
    Category abs = new Category();
    a = event.getSomething();
    if(!set.add(a))
    {
        b = event.getSomething2();
        c= event.getSomething();
    }
    else
    {
        d = event.getSomething();
        e = event.getSomething();
        tDat.add(d);
        tDat.add(e);
    }
    abs.setA(a);
    abs.setB(b);
    abs.setC(a);
    abs.settDat(tDat);
    catList.add(abs);   
}


This uses the same tDat instance for all categories in the loop. If you don’t want this list to be shared, new instances of ArrayList should be created inside the loop.

Remember this: Count the new.
Let's say your input (mainEventList) holds 10 items. How many new statements are executed by this code, in regards to tDat?
I see.. only 1 new, right at the top. That means there is only such object. One tDat list, shared by all categories. Each category has a reference to the same list. In java, new makes a new object, and variables reference objects. When you write this:
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> b = a;

a.add("Hi");
System.out.println(b.size());

You would get 1. Because, count the new, only one list exists here; a and b are like pages in different address books, but with the same address listed on it - they lead to the same house. The same thing is happening in your code. Each Category has a List<String> tDat field (or whatever you named it; it's not in your question), but they are all referring to the same list.
The solution is to fix count the new. There needs to be a new ArrayList<String> somewhere inside your for loop.
Note that = 'rewrites a page in an address book' (updates a reference), whereas . dereferences (it's the java equivalent of 'go to the house at the stated address and do something to the house or check some property of the house'). Hence why you don't run into this problem with those strings - you never do e.g. a.set("foo"), you do a = "foo". (Indeed, you can't run into this problem with strings; strings don't have any methods that modify them, so, you can share references all day long without running into problems).
